# Python: Selecting Object using String

Tags: python, object

I have a dataframe listing individual names, and for each one I have an identically-named object storing attributes about them. However, when iterating through the dataframe, I don't know how to use the listed name to access the correct object (which I want to pull an attribute from).

```
person = df._get_value(n, 'People')
getattr(person, 'Age')
```

When I run this, I get an Attribute Error because its attempting to access 'Age' in the string, but not the matching object. How should I convert the string dynamically so I can access the correct object?

Comment: You should give a sample of your dataframe to make the code reproducible. Besides, as advice you should give the error message as it is diplayed, there are a lot of useful information for us to understand the bug.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt function **import** (mind the double underscore). Sample code below

```
    module      = __import__("name of the package", globals(), locals(), ["moduleName"], 0)
    obj_class = getattr(module, "moduleName")
    cclass      = obj_class()
    
    getattr(cclass, "attributeName")
```

You can [view this doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.__import__) for more details on importlib